# R dplyr filter according 1 variable but keep this variable in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct

I wanna delete duplicated rows according a set of columns (all except 1) but i wanna keep that column in the df:

```
dfNew <- df %>% distinct(across(-column5))
```

The problem of that code is dfNew doesn't have the column5. I just wanna make the distinct excluding that column but keeping it in the final data frame.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `distinct(..., .keep_all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original columns, you can add '.keep_all = TRUE' as a parameter of your distinct command.